# PHP __callStatic as a factory

Tags: php, oop, factory

Since `__callStatic` was introduced in php 5.3, is it a good idea to use it when creating new classes instead of factory method?

For example, `$user = Model::User()` instead of `$user = Model::factory('User')`, and then:

```
public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
{
    $class_name = 'Model_' . $name;

    if( empty($arguments) )
    {
        return new $class_name();
    }
    else
    {
        $reflector = new ReflectionClass($class_name);

        return $reflector->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is heavily opinionated by definition, therefore all I can give is a 'best practice' answer.

Don't. While it's fine that something is possible, you're in practice obfuscating your code. Whoever comes after you to maintain the code will not expect this kind of behavior because it doesn't fit the paradigms taught at any IT education. Your code will be harder to maintain, document and share because you made an unconventional choice that, while perfectly valid and performant, does not offer any benefit over the accepted best practice.

Stick to commonly accepted standards and the developer after you will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems viable, but you can also make your classes extend a Facade like Laravel do:

```
class Facade
{
    static public function create()
    {
        if( empty($arguments) )
        {
            return new static;
        }
        else
        {
            $reflector = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());

            return $reflector->newInstanceArgs(func_get_args());
        }
    }
}

class User extends Facade
{

}
```

IMHO, the code is more explicit when `User::create()`